# Use Nova Authentication outside of Nova in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I love Laravel Nova. However sometimes I have an application that has very complex separate views. (Planning tools etc). These pages need to be hidden behind the some Gate / Authentication.

How do I add this to the blade file?

Anybody that has an example?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Answer (score 0):

The Easy way:
If you are using laravel 5,6 or 7 use laravel/ui auth scaffolding https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

If you are on laravel 8+ use jetstream, breeze or fortify
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#starter-kits

The Hard way:
You can leverage existing nova functionality to auth.
To see nova routes and controllers run

`php artisan route:list --name=nova`

```
| POST     | nova/login | nova.login | Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\LoginController@login
```

Create your own LoginController from Nova's `/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php`
Create your own trait from novas
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`

redirect to a new path.

I personally would use the starter kits or fortify.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this and the easiest option that I always do, is create a [Nova Tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html), lets say "Planning Tool". The tools provides a Vue Component that is free for you to do what you want. I setup an Iframe on the Vue Component and load the UI of the external page. Please make sure the external tools have the same gate configured as that of Nova.

I usually do this for Laravel packages that have a UI but doesn't have a Nova integration. I have Spatie's Mailcoach and few other Laravel packages loaded into Nova like this.

I know there are better ways to do this, but this is a quick and dirty way to get up and running when you don't have control over the external tool or if you don't want a lot of changes to get this up and running.

Hopefully this helps.